# IIS Smooth Streaming in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, silverlight, iis, video-streaming

How can I play [IIS Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/expand/SmoothStreaming) video in a WPF application. I know Silverlight has built-in support for it, but I can't find much information for WPF. Will the `MediaElement` control support this in WPF 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something has changed very recently, the only Windows Smooth Streaming client available is Silverlight. There is no support for Smooth Streaming in Windows Media Player or for other standalone Windows applications.