# WPF/C# - Decode/View IIS Smooth Streaming Content

Tags: c#, wpf, iis, video-streaming

I'm trying to write an application that is able to download the "chunks" sent by a IIS Smooth Streaming server and capture thumbnails of the video. I'm able to create the proper GET requests to download the chunks, but I'm having trouble finding a way to play or view the chunks I download.

Does anybody know of a way to combine and play/view the video sent? I know there are Silverlight players that will play the stream, but I'm trying to do this in a WPF application. Also any info on the file type that is sent from the server would be helpful in finding a way to play the content.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409930/iis-smooth-streaming-in-a-wpf-application

Comment: I'm not just looking for a wpf player, but any information on how to decode the files sent by a IIS Smooth Streaming server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the packages and extract the video and audio frames. Then you need to decode the video and audio. After this you need to render the decodec frames.

So best solution would be an DirectShow filter doing the download and splitting. With this filter you can then use the DirectShow system to decode and render the stream. Does anybody know if there is such a filter available?